# Problem with Ruby on Rails installation - How to use WAMP MySQL installation?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, windows-xp, installation

I did the following to install Ruby on Rails on Windows XP:

- Installed **rubyinstaller-1.9.2-p0.exe**
- **gem install rails**
- **gem install mysql2**
- **cd my_dir**
- **rails new my_app -d mysql**

The created **config/database.yml** contains the following MySQL configuration:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: first_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost
```

However, when I run **rails server** from **my_dir** I got the following error:

```
D:/Programs/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2
/mysql2.rb:2:in `require': 126: The specified module could not be found.   - D:/
Programs/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/1.
9/mysql2.so (LoadError)
...
```

along with the following pop-up message:

```
The application has failed to start because LIBMYSQL.dll was not found. Re-installing the application may fix this problem.
```

The problem, I guess, is the installation of MySQL.

I have WAMP installed, and I would like to use its MySQL installation.

I searched for **libmysql.dll** and indeed found it in: `my_path_to_wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.36\bin\libmysql.dll`

The question is how would I tell Rails to take this installation of MySQL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had this problem when installing the mysql gem before, and a quick fix is just to copy the libmysql.dll into your ruby bin folder.  I recently got rails running off of a WAMP MySQL server without a problem, so if this doesn't solve it post a more specific error message once you've sorted out the dependency issue and I'll look at my configuration.

EDIT: Just to be specific, I'm running XAMPP.

Comment: Copying `libmysql.dll` indeed solved the problem. However, I would like to know how to solve this issue "properly", without hacking like this. I would like to understand how Rails knows where MySQL installed, i.e. where does it looks for `libmysql.dll` ?

Comment: I think the proper way to fix it is to update your PATH to include the directory containing libmysql.dll.  I don't remember if I tried this before giving up and moving the dll.  If you try this and it works, let me know; we actually do this a lot where I work, and it's just an accepted hack.