# Ruby mysql2 Error

Tags: mysql, ruby

I am getting the following error

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': 126: The specified module could not be found.   - C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/1.9/mysql2.so (LoadError)
```

When trying to run this script...

```
require "mysql2"

client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => "localhost", :username => "root", :password => "system32")
results = client.query("SELECT * FROM project1_nodes").each do |row|
  puts row
end
```

Any ideas?

Cheers
Martin

Comment: Not an *exact* duplicate, but this solution should also solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241068/rubymine-3-0-setup-on-windows-7 ((just adjust the windows paths to the correct paths, assuming you're not using windows).

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121524/problem-with-ruby-on-rails-installation-how-to-use-wamp-mysql-installation

Comment: Sorted that one but now I am getting this error - C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': 193: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.   - C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/1.9/mysql2.so (LoadError) -  Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess you are running ROR on windows. So follow these steps.

1. make sure you installed mysql correctlt.
2. copy libmysql.dll(from mysql installation directory) file into you C:/Ruby193/bin folder
3. now remove older mysql installed gems.
4. reinstall mysql gem.

This might fix your problem.

Comment: I am running Ruby, no rails. I have tried this but I am getting still the error - C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': 193: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. - C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/1.9/mysql2.so (LoadError) - Any ideas?

Comment: This answer did sort the original problem, though I still have an issue with the new error message, I have opened up a seperate question for it. Thanks

Comment: [installing-mysql-on-windows-7-x64-and-using-ruby-with-it](http://blog.mmediasys.com/2011/07/07/installing-mysql-on-windows-7-x64-and-using-ruby-with-it/) explains the problem and solution in more detail... though this is for mysql gem, it also worked for mysql2.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using RVM, are you using a specific gemset?

I've had similar issues and setting specifying a specific gemset has fixed my issues. For example, I'll installed a gem, but then won't be able to load it with a `require 'example_gem_name'` call. This fixed my issues,

```
rvm gemset use gemset_name  
gem install mysql2  
gem list mysql2
```

Also, to set the RVM default gemset (so you don't have to every time),

```
rvm use 1.9.3@gemset_name --default
```