# Rails and Windows 8 - "%1 is not a valid Win32 application" error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

### The Goal

**I'm trying to get Rails going** for the first time **and connected to MySQL**, all on my local machine. As far as I can tell, Rails is installed according to spec. My setup is:

- Ruby 1.9.3 (installed via the latest version of the RubyInstaller)
- Rails 3.2.8
- Windows 8
- WAMP (which has the MySQL database I'd like to connect Rails to)

### The Problem

When I run the command `rails s`, I receive the following error:

```
C:/wamp/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in 'require': 193: %1 is not a valid Win32 application - C:/wamp/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/1.9/mysql2.so (LoadError)
    from C:/wamp/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/
lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in '<top (required)>'
    from C:/wamp/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/
lib/mysql2.rb:9:in 'require'
    from C:/wamp/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/
lib/mysql2.rb:9:in '<top (required)>'
    from C:/wamp/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/
runtime.rb:68:in 'require'
    from C:/wamp/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/
runtime.rb:68:in 'block (2 levels) in require'
    from C:/wamp/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/
runtime.rb:66:in 'each'
    from C:/wamp/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/
runtime.rb:66:in 'block in require'
    from C:/wamp/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/
runtime.rb:55:in 'each'
    from C:/wamp/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/
runtime.rb:55:in 'require'
    from C:/wamp/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler.
rb:128:in 'require'
    from C:/Users/Andrew/Desktop/rails_test/simple_cms/config/application.rb
:7:in '<top (required)>'
    from C:/wamp/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/c
ommands.rb:53:in 'require'
    from C:/wamp/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/c
ommands.rb:53:in 'block in <top (required)>'
    from C:/wamp/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/c
ommands.rb:50:in 'tap'
    from C:/wamp/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/c
ommands.rb:50:in '<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in 'require'
    from script/rails:6:in '<main>'
```

So there seems to be a problem with the `mysql2` gem? My reading has shown me that ~1-2 years ago it was a big issue, but I was of the understanding that the problems with it had been resolved at this point. (And if it is indeed better than `mysql`, then I'd like to use it!)

### What I've Tried

- I *was* getting the error "126: the specified module could not be found"; while looking up information regarding that, I came across the suggestion to copy "libmysql.dll" to Ruby's bin folder. It apparently fixed the 126 error, but now I'm getting this 193 error.
- Completely uninstalling Ruby, Rails, and reinstalling fresh multiple times using various different guides.
- Found [this blog post](http://myrailslearnings.wordpress.com/2012/07/03/error-cdevruby193librubysite_ruby1-9-1rubygemscustom_require-rb36in-require-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application/) where the author found that another program he had running was preventing `rails s` from working, so I closed everything and tried again. Nothing.
- Spent the past two days reading blogs and different posts by folks having the same issue, but it seems like *all* of them are from over a year ago, linking to (apparently successful!) fixes where the links are, unfortunately, now dead.

If any further information is needed, please let me know! I've been Googling this problem for a large part of the past 48 hours to absolutely no avail. Any direction would be appreciated. :) Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby mysql2 Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936523/ruby-mysql2-error)

Comment: Actually, yeah, I saw that one previously, but unfortunately none of the listed fixes worked. :/

Answer (score 1):

OP here. I just got Rails working. Unfortunately not to spec (I'm using SQLlite instead of the MySQL installation installed via WAMP), but it's functioning. I used the [RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/) and set it up according to their instructions, and it works brilliantly. I recommend it to anybody who's having the same problem I was!

Comment: The RailsInstaller is deff the way to go. Also I used the mysql2 gem that seemed to caused the problem. Uninstalling that gem and running sqlite solved the problem.