# Error during install gem in ROR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I am installing mysql gem for my application but i have an error

[image]

please any one tell me how can i install MySQL gem

Comment: Please follow this solution. Duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936523/ruby-mysql2-error/9938006#9938006

Comment: What command you fired..please tell me

Comment: @MuhammadSannan This is not a duplicate one you linked..

Comment: @Arup Rakshit: Looks like Ankit missing mysql dll files, by following above url might fix this error.

Comment: @MuhammadSannan Did you see the error `undefined method '[]'` one ? :)

Comment: Try this.. `gem install [your gem name] --debug --backtrace` which will tell you from where the error is coming..

Comment: @arup i run this command
gem install [mysql2] ---debug --backtrace
it give me again a error , could not find gem

Comment: same error as in screen shot

Answer (score 0):

gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.11'. Its a generic error.