# Ruby On Rails: Error on rake db:migrate

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake

I am pretty new to rails environment. I am learning it from `Pluralsight's Ruby on rails for .Net Development`:
I am trying to run rake db:migrate and getting the following error:

```
D:\Rails\MyBlog>rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
126: The specified module could not be found.   - C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/li
b/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/1.9/mysql2.so
D:/Rails/MyBlog/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
D:/Rails/MyBlog/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

The only difference between the course I am learning and my implementation is that I am using MySql and the course uses SQL Server 2008.

What could be the reason behind the error? Any Help?

Comment: can you provide your gemfile?

Comment: visit this answer here @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936523/ruby-mysql2-error

Comment: @Uandl.. Which gem file do you want.. Where can I find it? I am pretty new to this so I cannot answer your question prooperly..

Comment: @AlokAnand.. I tried the method in your link and now it says something like Successfully installed mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32...
Installing RDoc documentation for mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32...

D:\Rails\MyBlog>rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
Incorrect MySQL client library version! This gem was compiled for 6.0.0 but the
client library is 5.0.41.
D:/Rails/MyBlog/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
D:/Rails/MyBlog/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
bundle install
```

That, you've probably done.

After that, go [Here](http://maxivak.com/installing-mysql2-gem-on-ruby-1-9-2-and-rails-3-0-5-on-windows/)